# Can you make an array of dictionaries in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I have an array which contains a list of the countries in the world. Is there any way I can make an array of dictionaries, which each dictionary contain a list of the countries depending on the alphabet. For example:

```
  NSArray =>

NSDictionary
    headerTitle => ‘A’
    rowValues => {”A”, “Aa”, “Aaa”, “Aaaa”}
NSDictionary
    headerTitle => ‘B’
    rowValues => {”B”, “Bb”, “Bbb”, “Bbbb”}
etc.
```

Comment: Yes, there's nothing special about dictionaries (or arrays, for that matter). Just make them and put them in the array like you would any other object.

Comment: Sure.  `NSArray* ary = @[@{@"A":@"blah", @"B":@"bah"},@{@"A":@"bah", @"B": @"blah"}];`

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can, but why not do it the other way around - have a dictionary with keys which are the letters of the alphabet, and values which are an array of countries that start with that letter.  Here is how you could do it with literals:

```
NSDictionary *countriesListedByLetter = @{@"A" : @[@"Albania",@"Argentina"], @"B" : @[@"Bolivia", @"Burma"]};
```

Comment: +1 for not only answering the question, but suggesting a better design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve exactly what you have listed, you can do this:

```
NSArray* array = @[ 
    @{ 
        @"A" : @[ @"Aa", @"Aaa", @"Aaaa" ] 
     }, 
    @{ 
        @"B" : @[ @"Bb", @"Bbb", @"Bbbb" ] 
     }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the object for this purpose:

```
   @interface CountriesByLetter : NSObject

      @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *letter;
      @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *countries;

   @end
```

And store this objects in an array.